# Существует ли возможность нарисовать в одном канвасе другой?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Я пытаюсь сделать двойную буферизацию для канваса. Для этого я хотел использовать два холста - в один я рисую, как в буфер, а потом, когда все на него отрисовал, все его изображение копирую во второй.

Собственно вопрос с копированием. Как можно всю картинку из одного канваса нарисовать во другом?

Answer (score 2):

Все, решил проблему:

```
canvas_context2.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);
```

Где `canvas_context2` - контекст канваса, куда рисуем, а `canvas1` - канвас, откуда берем изображение.